# How to get week id in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to get the week id for the current date in Snowflake

I tried the Following query.

```
SELECT to_number(to_char(to_date(current_date),'w')) from dual
```

This is not working,
error : Numeric: value w is not recognized
How to solve the problem

Thank you

Comment: _"How to solve the problem"_ - you've explained what you've tried, but you haven't explained what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [WEEKOFYEAR or WEEKISO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html#usage-notes) should be enough. You will want to read the how it [week is defined](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html#calendar-weeks-and-weekdays), to make sure it meet your needs.

```
SELECT 
    current_date() AS a,
    WEEKOFYEAR( a ),
    WEEKISO( a )
;
```

gives:

| A | WEEKOFYEAR( A ) | WEEKISO( A ) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-23 | 8 | 8 |